# How to show it?

Tags: discriminant-analysis

Could you give me some hints how to show that the function
$$f(a):=\frac{(\mathbb E [a^t X_1]-\mathbb E [a^t X_2])^2}{\mathrm {Var} (a^t X_1-a^t X_2)}$$ is maximised by a vector $$a \propto C^{-1} (\mu_1-\mu_2) ?$$
$X_1 \sim  N (\mu_1, C)$ and $X_2 \sim N(\mu_2, C)$ are two random vectros. All I managed to do was to calculate that 
$$ \frac{(\mathbb E [a^t X_1]-\mathbb E [a^t X_2])^2}{\mathrm {Var} (a^t X_1-a^t X_2)} = \frac{(a^t (\mu_1-\mu_2))^2}{a^t 2Ca}=\frac{a^t Aa}{a^t B a},$$
$$A:=(\mu_1-\mu_2)(\mu_1-\mu_2)^t, \quad B:=2C$$
and 
$$ [Df(a)]=\frac{2a^tA(a^tBa)-(a^t A a)2a^t B}{(a^t B a)^2}.$$
I don't how to proceed ;/

Comment: The question seems clear (but way out of my expertise). But the title won't attract the people who can answer. Please provide a full title so your question will get looked at (and maybe answered) by those who have the requisite knowledge.

Comment: If this is a study exercise, consider adding the self-study tag.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the square-root $B^{1/2}$of a positive-definite matrix $B$ such that
$$B^{1/2} B^{1/2} = B.$$
Using this notation, write $f(a)$ by $b=B^{-1/2}a$. Then, we have
$$f(b) = \dfrac{b^{\rm T} \tilde{A}b}{b^{\rm T} b},$$
where $\tilde{A}=B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}$. Then, use the Cauchy-Schwarz to find the maximum at some $b_0$ and transform it back to $a_0=B^{1/2}b_0$.